# Developing CLDC or J2ME applications under Mac OSX?

Tags: java, macos, java-me, cldc, java-wireless-toolkit

I have noticed that Oracle now has released a [Java Platform Micro Edition SDK for OSX](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30_mac.jsp). It works, it can compile the provided examples and the included phone emulator works too. But how do I compile my own J2ME project from Ant or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/)?

There are a lot of related [jars](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30_mac.jsp) but they are all inside the ".app" in the /Applications directory. Eclipse does not like it when I put a toolchain path to inside the ".app".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the EclipseME plugin? It helps integrate JavaME (J2ME) development into Eclipse. Here's a guide for getting it working with Eclipse:

[Eclipse ME / Configuration](http://eclipseme.org/docs/configuring.html)

You'll find plenty of documentation and how tos.

If you don't like EclipseME, I personally found Netbeans very good for mobile development:

[Netbeans JavaME Page](http://netbeans.org/features/javame/)

Also, you weren't specific in your question, but the link you've provided seems to indicate you want to use MTJ. In that case, use this documentation to guide you through:

[Eclipse MTJ - Getting Started](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/development/tutorial/gettingstarted.php)

Comment: Yes, but EclipseME does not include the J2ME jars and tools.

Comment: In the link I included, it shows you how to import the devices from the SDK for use within Eclipse. Also, with EclipseME installed, you'll find the settings related to many J2ME tools and config in Eclipse's prefences, under the "J2ME" heading.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ANT I have simply copied over the required jars from the Windows SDK and just used the pre verifier and javac from the osx 3.0 sdk, works well!